# jQuery doesn't append() to a newly opened tab

Tags: jquery

I have a problem when i try to use the append() method to insert html into a new tab that i opened from a click on a button in my main page. I have searched on the web for answers and i didn't find any regarding my problem. The only suggestion i found was saying to use html() instead of append(), but that doesn't work either. This the part of my code with the problem in question. You can disregard the ajax call and the variable part since from debugging i can see that it works. #games is on my main page and #editGames is the section i'm trying to append() to on my second page. Thank you!

`

```
$("#games").on("click", ".editeaza", function() {
    window.open("edit.html");
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajax({
          url:
          "https://games-world.herokuapp.com/games/" +
          $(this)
            .parent()
            .attr("id"),
        method: "GET"
      }).then(function(game) {
        var id = game._id;
        var title = game.title;
        var releaseDate = game.releaseDate;
        var genre = game.genre;
        var publisher = game.publisher;
        var image = game.imageUrl;
        var description = game.description;

        $("#editGames").append("<p>I AM DUMB!</p>");
      });
    });
  });
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the other window and use it's document context to access elements in it once it has loaded

Try

```
$("#games").on("click", ".editeaza", function() {
  // other window reference
  var otherWindow = window.open("edit.html");
  // let other window load before accessing elements
  $(otherWindow).on('load', function() {
    // document in other window
    var $doc = $(this.document);
    // find() within other document 
    $doc.find("#editGames").append("<p>I AM DUMB!</p>");
  });
});
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yKUZJ4EypnTfsBgWnkFC?p=preview)

---

A simpler approach would be pass the `id` to the url and do the ajax inside the other page by parsing the url to get the id

```
$("#games").on("click", ".editeaza", function() {
    window.open("edit.html?item_id=" + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think i am doing something else wrong because your first solution doesn't work for me, although it should because you plunker demo works for me. Could you please elaborate more on the second solution since you said it's a simpler approach. What should i do after i get the id from the URL in the second page? Do i need a new script page to link to that one or can i just use my normal script page and just do the AJAX call and other stuff in a separate function?

Comment: You would do the ajax in the other page, or use server side code to render the data. Too many unknowns as to why my first solution isn't working

Comment: Thank you very much i made it work using your second suggestion with the URL. I didn't know about sending the id like that. Again thank you I was wracking my brains out for the past 3 hours.